# Ember access controller attribute within common route/controller mxiin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a attribute defined in my controller as

```
myControllerAttr
```

Also there is a common mixin extended by both the route/controller (`my-mixin.js`)

Now in my-mixin.js, there are various methods which get called from both route/controller class

My question is within these mixin methods, how do I access the controller attribute myControllerAttr

since `this.myControllerAttr` may not work always

It would depend on whether the method was invoked from a route or controller class

Should I add an if condition OR what is the best way ?

So to summarize, my question is how do I check between

```
this.get('myControllerAttr') V/s
this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('myControllerAttr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but it might be.

```
// mixins/type-checker.js
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  isRoute: computed('target',function(){
    const isUndefined = typeof this.get('target') === 'undefined'
    return isUndefined ? true : false
  }),
  isController: computed('target',function(){
    const isUndefined = typeof this.get('target') === 'undefined'
    return isUndefined ? false : true
  }),
  getAttribute(attr){
    let attrYouWant
    if(this.get('isController')){
      attrYouWant = this.get(attr)
    }else{
      attrYouWant = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get(attr)
    }
    return attrYouWant
  }
})
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
//routes/application.js

import TypeChecker from '../mixins/type-checker'

export default Ember.Route.extend(TypeChecker, {
  actions: {
    test(){
      const testProp = this.getAttribute('prop')
      console.log(testProp)
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e56dabbaf9bd3482e61d6b62c668a8d7) where I have implemented what I propose.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have got the question very correctly..but just one thing...In both the places (isRoute & isController), you are checking for same thing... const isUndefined = typeof this.get('target') === 'undefined'

Please confirm

Comment: Yes, so the idea is that, it will always check that target is defined, because if it is, you're in a controller, if not, your in a route. I searched through the source on github and checked routes and controllers to find something a bit 'nicer', and there is properties like isController and isRoute etc. but I'm unable to easily access them. But this should do just fine for now.